# Qt C++ Connect QSlider to QWebView's setTextSizeMultiplier

Tags: c++, qt, connect, qwebview, qslider

How do I connect QSlider to QWebView's setTextSizeMultiplier in Qt? I want to web's text to get smaller or larger depending on the slider's value when it changes.

This is how I'm trying to do it, but not getting anywhere:
thesliderbar is QSlider and vweb is QWebView

```
connect(thesliderbar,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),ui->vweb,SLOT(setTextSizeMultiplier(int)));
```

Comment: what is the result of connect?

Comment: Object::connect: No such slot QWebView::setTextSizeMultiplier(int)
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'vweb')

Comment: the slot is defined? Have you tried to rebuild your project?

Comment: Yea. I've cleaned, rebuild, and same error???

Comment: It is not a slot, not even a signal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html for here you can see that setTextSizeMultiplier it is not a slot so you can not connect/compile...

EDIT1: also function signature is different. You are using int as a parameter but it is a qreal...

Make a slot in your class, connect to it and update the text multiplier from there.

Comment: How do you create custom public slots in Qt4? I've tried and they don't work?